# How to create trusted publisher in C# application?

Tags: c#, security, certificate, administrator

I have a C# application that requires you to run as administrator. When it asks the user to run as administrator it says from an unknown publisher. How can i change that to a trusted publisher or add a signed certificate in c#?

I would like a free solution. maybe self signed certificates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I digitally sign an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128205/how-can-i-digitally-sign-an-executable)

Comment: I would like a free solution. maybe self signed certificates